# Primefaces commandButton not called when panel visibled

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

i have some problem when calling commandButton in primefaces

here's my code

```
<h:form>
    <some component...>
         <p:ajax update="tipe" oncomplete="PF('tipePanel').show()"/>
    </some component...>
    <p:panel id="tipe" visible="false" rendered="true" widgetVar="tipePanel">                   
          <p:commandButton value="Add" 
                   actionListener="#{soal.addDetailForm()}" 
                   rendered="true" />  
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

The problem is the button can't be called when the panel is showed, but if i put the panel `visible="true"` from the start, the button can be called. Any idea why ?

And how should i make the button works when the panel is showed. Thanks

Comment: What it means visible="false" and rendered="true"? if button not fired it mean somewhere page have exception try to replace with h:commanbutton for testing purpose and see it fired or not?

Comment: How do you change visibility of the component?

Comment: well i figured it out my self. i just need to add attribute async="true" than its worked!